# "Out of Memory" error when embedding an image to a .rdl file in Power BI Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, error-handling, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I've recently started using Power BI Report Builder to build .rdl reports. I want to add an image to my report so followed these instructions from Microsoft - [Embed an Image in a Report (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/embed-an-image-in-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

However, I get this error whenever I click the "ok" button in the Image Properties window -[image: Error Message]

Here are the properties of the image I am trying to embed - 
[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I notice that the image is blocked so it may just be that and a misleading error message. Try unblocking the image first. Then if that does not work, can you try compressing the image down to a smaller size and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: You may be hitting the report limit size of 4MB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-and-snapshot-size-limits?view=sql-server-ver15 resize or reduce the bit depth of your jpeg,

Comment: following on from the comment by  @Jon you could possibly use external images files instead of embedding them, although this may not be feasible is the image location is not accessible from the users client PC.